# Trying to distribute images evenly with css

Tags: css

Im trying to create a slide of small images and that on each slide the images are evenly distributed horizontally. Found an [interesting technique](http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/) on css-tricks.com and a very straighforward [working example](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/nfyGk) but i haven't been able to replicate it.

Here's the html of a slide

```
<div class="item active">
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css following the mentioned technique

```
div.sites .carousel-inner .item div {
  font-size: 0.1px;
  text-align: justify;
}

div.sites .carousel-inner .item div:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.sites .carousel-inner .item div a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can see the code working at the bottom of [this site](http://activomultimedia.com/husj/), under the title "OTROS SITIOS"

**EDIT**: My girlfriend tried [my code in CodePen](http://s.codepen.io/anon/pen/oBsDd) and it worked nicely. im guessing it must be some global style that's interfering with it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Difficult to tell what you are asking for, but changing `text-align: justify` to `text-align: center` makes the list of 100x100 images all centered...?  The slider works pretty nicely after that.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is for the images to distribute evenly in the horizontal space. Like when you justify a text that all the words distribute across the line. You can check the working example in the question to see a demo of what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the html structure starting from the div sites and pasted it on CodePen alongside with your proposed css code.
I saw that you missed the escape character between the `</a>` and `<a>`

When I added it, the code worked perfectly :)